# Yongnuo YN720: Can I use master and slave without a trigger attached?

Tags: flash, yongnuo

I bought two flash YN720 with the understanding that I didn't need a trigger to fire both master and slave flashes. Not sure how to set them up? I have two RF 630N triggers but I would rather not use them. Is it possible?

This is the blurb from manufacturer:
'Built into it is a 2.4 GHz wireless transceiver, allowing it to be fired remotely at distances of up to 328' or used as a master to directly control the mode and output of compatible flashes. Additionally, it can also be used as an optical slave for multi-flash setups without radio transmission. '

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as the 'Master' is attached to the camera's hot shoe. Otherwise you need a radio trigger, such as a YN560-TX or RF-603 to control both of them off camera. In that scenario, the trigger on the camera's hot shoe would be the 'Master' and both off camera flashes would be in 'wireless' radio mode. You would not need an additional receiver attached to the flashes, their internal radios are capable of receiving radio signals from Yongnuo's YN560/RF605/RF603 radio system.

If you set the off-camera flash(es) to "optical slave" mode (S1, S2), they will ignore the built-in radio receiver and only react to optical triggering. They need to be set to a wireless receiver mode, such as YN560 or RF-603. The YN560-TX will give you more control over the flashes remotely than an RF-603 will.